# Saving webpages to localbox

Tags: linux, macos, http

Is there any way in which I can download all the first visits to a webpage to my local box and all the subsequent visits will retrieve the data from the local box rather than the internet? That is, like a service is running on a port and if i access that port and not the HTTP port, i get the data from local box?

I need to use this service for parsing webpages whose contents might change every time, so that i get the same content to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a caching proxy such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

The squid service stores the webpages locally and the next requests return the stored file.

Comment: thanks. i am already familiar with it.. it just never occured to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about a proxy server

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use this service for parsing webpages whose contents might change

Have a look for a spidering engine, e.g. pavuk.